# Keep a form opened waiting for asynchronous method response

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question regarding a somewhat simple problem, but I think with many solutions and I don't know what would be the best.

I have the following scenario including:

1. ApplicationForm
2. Proxy (Client -> Server side)
3. Possible error message dialog.

The form sends a request to do something on the server side and the form closes (this is the current implementation). I changed this so the method that is being called on the proxy, server side returns a string value that contains an error message if something fails.

The problem is that I want to display a message box when the response comes back if the message is not String.Empty

I do the following:

1. Call method and assign value returned to a property field.
2. Create a timer that has an event that fires after 4 seconds.
   ... Meanwhile the form closes...
3. Timer event fires, Check the property for a possible error in the string and fire another event that calls a method on the form and displays a message box.

The thing is, I would like to keep the form opened and after the user clicks OK on the message dialog box the form should close.

Any idea is good.

Comment: what triggers the asynchronous operation? Is it the pressing of the OK button?

Comment: Simply disabling the form while the request is in progress should to the trick. If you want to keep it responsive though, you could keep an instance-level flag indicating that the request is in progress, and test that inside the `FormClosing` event handler, setting `e.Cancel = true` thereby preventing the user from closing the form if the flag is set. Finally, you could wrap your async operation in a `Task`, save the reference to the `Task` at the start of the operation, and block on its completion inside the `FormClosing` handler, also preventing the form from closing prematurely.

Comment: I will try the idea with a flag that is checked inside the form closing event. Thank you

Comment: @AlinArgintaru, by the way: is it possible to trigger the async operation more than once during the lifetime of the form? If yes, you will need something a little more sophisticated.

Comment: No, just once when the OK button is pressed and the form is closed.